# How to run environment initialization shell script from Dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, docker, openvino

I am trying to build an API wrapped in a docker image that serves Openvino model. How do I run the "setupvars.sh" from Dockerfile itself so that my application can access it?

I have tried running the script using RUN. For ex:  RUN /bin/bash setupvars.sh
or RUN ./setupvars.sh . However, none of them work and I get ModelNotFoundError: no module named openvino

```
RUN $INSTALL_DIR/install_dependencies/install_openvino_dependencies.sh
RUN cd /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites && sudo ./install_prerequisites_tf.sh
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /openvino /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $INSTALL_DIR/bin/setupvars.sh"
RUN echo "source $INSTALL_DIR/bin/setupvars.sh" >> /root/.bashrc
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
RUN python3 -m pip install opencv-python
RUN python3 test.py
```

I want OpenVino accessible to my gunicorn application that will serve the model in a docker image

Answer (score 0):

Next commands works for me.

```
ARG OPENVINO_DIR=/opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk


# Unzip the OpenVINO installer
RUN cd ${APP_DIR} && tar -xvzf l_openvino_toolkit*

# installing OpenVINO dependencies
RUN cd ${APP_DIR}/l_openvino_toolkit* && \
    ./install_cv_sdk_dependencies.sh

# installing OpenVINO itself
RUN cd ${APP_DIR}/l_openvino_toolkit* && \
    sed -i 's/decline/accept/g' silent.cfg && \
    ./install.sh --silent silent.cfg

# Setup the OpenVINO environment
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ${OPENVINO_DIR}/bin/setupvars.sh"
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. Getting the same module not found error

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-run it every time you start the container, because those variables are only for the session.

Option 1: 
Run your application something like this:

```
CMD /bin/bash -c "source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh && python test.py"
```

Option 2 (not tested):
Add the source command to your .bashrc so it will be run every time on startup

```
# Assuming running as root
RUN echo "/bin/bash -c 'source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh'" >> ~root/.bashrc
CMD python test.py
```

For the rest of the Dockerfile, there is a guide here (also not tested, and it doesn't cover the above):
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_docker_linux.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the two previous answers, the `setupvars.sh` script sets the environment variables required by OpenVINO.

But rather than running this every time, you can add the variables to your Dockerfile. While writing your Dockerfile run:

`CMD /bin/bash -c "source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh && printenv"`

This will give you the values that the environment variables are set to. You might also want to run `printenv` without setting the OpenVINO variables:

`CMD /bin/bash printenv`

Comparing the two outputs will let you figure out exactly what the `setupvars.sh` script is setting.

Once you know the values set by the script, you can set these as part of the Dockerfile using the `ENV` instruction. I **wouldn't copy** this because it's likely to be specific to your setup, but in my case, this ended up looking like:

```
ENV PATH=/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/openvino/opencv/lib:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/ngraph/lib:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/tbb/lib::/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/lib:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/omp/lib:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/gna/lib:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/mkltiny_lnx/lib:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64
ENV INTEL_CVSDK_DIR=/opt/intel/openvino
ENV OpenCV_DIR=/opt/intel/openvino/opencv/cmake
ENV TBB_DIR=/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/tbb/cmake
# The next one will be whatever your working directory is
ENV PWD=/workspace
ENV InferenceEngine_DIR=/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/share
ENV ngraph_DIR=/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/ngraph/cmake
ENV SHLVL=1
ENV PYTHONPATH=/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3.6:/opt/intel/openvino/python/python3:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/tools/post_training_optimization_toolkit:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/accuracy_checker:/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer
ENV HDDL_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl
ENV _=/usr/bin/printenv
```